# The type already contains a definition.

Tags: c#

My program for creating and testing a rectangle keeps telling me the "type already contains a definition for width, area, and perimeter". I cant figure out what I am doing wrong, its preventing me from building the file.

```
{
public class Rectangle
{
    private float length;
    private float width;
    private float perimeter;
    private float area;
    public Rectangle(float I = 1.0F, float w = 1.0F)
    {
        length = I;
        width = w;
        perimeter = 2 * (length + width);
        area = length * width;
    }
    public float Length
    {
        get
        {
            return length;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0.0 && value < 20.0)
                length = value;
            else
                throw new
                ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length value",
                value, "Length must be 0-20");
        }
    }
    public float width
    {
        get
        {
            return width;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0.0 && value < 20.0)
                width = value;
            else
                throw new
                ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Width value",
                value, "Width must be 0-20");
        }
    }
    public float area
    {
        get
        {
            return area;
        }
    }
    public float perimeter
    {
        get
        {
            return perimeter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two things named `width` - lowercase `w`. Same with `area` and `perimeter`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I've viewed these forums a fair amount, never posted until now. Thanks again for the assistance!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use different names for your properties and fields. Simply change first letters of your property names to upper case like you did with `Length`.

Comment: And for double security (clarity), name the private field `_width`.